# Injective modules

Tags: modules, injective-module

We know that for all $n \neq 0$,  $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an  injective module  over itself. But $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is also a PID, then since it is injective by  Baer's criterion $\overline{x}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})= \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for all non zero $\overline{x} \in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$.

If we consider the example $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ and $\overline{x}=\overline{2}$ then  $\overline{2}(\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z})=\{\overline{0},\overline{2}\}$ which is properly contained in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. What is the wrong thing I am doing? Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The crucial error is that $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is not a PID for all $n$. Indeed, it's not even an integral domain unless $n$ is prime.

Comment: Yes I agree with you Thank you... $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is a principal ideal ring right? That is every ideal is principal?

Comment: Remember: PID = Principal Ideal Domain. The domain part is the problem. $\mathbb{Z}/n \mathbb{Z}$ may have zero divisors, and so may not be a domain. (Example: $2 \times 2 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$.)

Comment: I want to prove an exercise in Weibel's introduction to homological algebra.  Let d|m and there is a prime p such that p|d and $p| \frac{m}{d}$. Then I want to conclude that $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ is not injective over $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. Can you help me?

Comment: I might be able to, but that was not the subject of your question. Please consider accepting my answer and then ask your question separately.

Comment: Yes I agree with you.  and made a comment above.